# Unity. Почему пропадает кнопка активации скрипта в инспекторе?

Tags: unity3d

В общем, заметил, что в инспекторе в параметрах скрипта кнопки активации иногда просто нет. Почему такое может происходить?

[image: скрипт в инспекторе без птички]
[image: скрипт в инспекторе с птичкой]

PS: На представленных скриншотах можно заметить неровности текстов, они есть, потому что это разные скрипты и я заменил их названия на *TestSprite*. Это пришлось сделать, потому что я не знаю, из-за чего пропадает кнопка, и не могу смоделировать ситуацию иначе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функций типа `Start, OnEnable,OnDisable, Update` и т.д. активруют эту галку.
Если в скрипте нет подобных функций, то галки нет. Функция `Awake`, например, не активирует галку.